# Android EditText: don't break line before line end

Tags: android, android-edittext, line-breaks

I am using an `EditText` (`inputType=textMultiLine`, monospace) in a (Brainf*ck) programming application. I want the lines to wrap, but only after covering the full width of the `EditText`. Instead, the `EditText` breaks the lines at seemingly random points, assuming that I am typing words.

I.e., I do not want

```
++++++++[>++++[>++>+++>++
+>+<<<<-]>+>+>->>+
[<]<-]>>.>---.+++++++..+
++.>>.<-.<.++
+.------.--------.>>+.>+
+.
```

but

```
++++++++[>++++[>++>+++>++
+>+<<<<-]>+>+>->>+[<]<-]>
>.>---.+++++++..+++.>>.<-
.<.+++.------.--------.>>
+.>++.
```

Any ideas on how to accomplish this? I have tried using `breakStrategy` but had no success.

Comment: your example is too hard to understand

Comment: The content of the example is not important, it is only the formatting that I am concerned about

Answer (score 0):

try to use

```
edtText.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
        @Override
        public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {
        }

        @Override
        public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {

        }
    });
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but adding an empty `TextWatcher` does not work. Did you mean to put something in it?

Comment: @TeinvanderLugt of course. you can range or do whatever you want with your text during changing or at once after that